# Should 'favorite' stars migrate with a question?

Tags: feature-request, migration, bookmarks

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-maximum-disk-usage-for-a-user) was migrated from SO to [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) a short time ago, and a user on our site [asked if his 'favorite' star would come over with the migraton](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5947328#5947328).

It turns out it didn't - but it seems to me it wouldn't be a bad thing if it did, especially (but perhaps not only) if:

- the user is registered on both sites
- the migration happened soon after the question was favorited
- the question isn't closed on the target site

Is there a good reason why this does not happen?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because there's no guarantee the user exists on the target site and there'd be nobody to link the favorite to, combined with the low payoff (nobody asked)...

Comment: I wonder how expensive it would be to check if a question was starred 300+ times (can happen in cases of old questions, and we do on occasion migrate them to a new site if there's a compelling reason and coordination). Presumably, nobody thought of it, or doing it was ruled out because of logistics. Migrations used to be _extremely_ fragile, but bugs related to that have not surfaced lately. Curious to see the dev take on this.

Answer (score 3):

There are arguments for both sides, so I think it is best to sum them up without giving a final yes or no.

Reasons to migrate the favorite:

- it is odd to have a favorite on site A while the question actually resides on site B (migration target);
- any others? Not that I am aware of.

Reasons to keep the favorite on the site it originally was favorited:

- the user favorited it there, so usually a user will get back to find it;
- migration might get rejected, so moving favorites could end up useless;
- a user doesn't have to be a regular on the target site, or check his user profile regularly there.